# MS Visual Studios Link error. 2010 and 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, visual-studio-2013

A long time ago I tried to set up an SDK into visual studio 2010.
I some how messed the whole ide up. Everytime I run a project is gives me a link error for "DarkSDK" (the sdk I tried to install) and the project won't build.

I have tried reinstalling VS 2010 and still get the error on every project.  I have just gotten VS 2013 and I get the same error.

Is there a way I can restore my directories, and input back to default? It was so long ago that I don't remember how to undo whatever I did to mess it up.

Thanks, 
Caleb

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's causing the problem, but since you haven't used VS in a while I'd consider going to `Tools` -> `Import and Export Settings...` -> `Reset All Settings`.  This will give you an option to back up whatever settings you have, which I would recommend just in case.

Comment: It didn't work. I still get the error... fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'DarkSDK.lib'